# Asp.net core SendMail Attached File always null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to send the filled and scanned application form I received from the user to info@weex with an attached file, but the Iform variable always returns null

**This is my Mail code in Controller**

```
HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult SendMail(string weexformname, string weexformemail, string weexformphone, string weexformmessage, IFormFile AttachedFile)
    {


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.weex.com.tr", 587);
        //Server Credentials
        NetworkCredential NC = new NetworkCredential();
        NC.UserName = "info@weex.com.tr";
        NC.Password = "**";
        //assigned credetial details to server
        client.Credentials = NC;
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("info@weex.com.tr", "info", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("info@weex.com.tr");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = "<b>Mail : </b>  " + weexformemail + "<br/>" +
         "<b>Telefon Numarası : </b>  " + weexformphone + "<br/>" +
         "<b>Mesaj : </b>  " + weexformmessage;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachedFile.OpenReadStream(), AttachedFile.FileName));
        message.Subject = "Weex.com.tr iletişim formu üzerinden gönderen kişinin adı " + weexformname;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.SendCompleted += new
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

        string userState = "test message1";
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

**This is my HTML Form**

```
<form asp-action="SendMail" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="form-container signin-form">
    <h2 style="font-family:Calibri">Bilgilerinizi Doldurun ve Dosyayı Seçin</h2>

    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" id="weexformname" name="weexformname" style="font-family:Calibri;border-radius:20px" placeholder="İsim Soyisim" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

    <input type="text" class="form-control mt-4" id="weexformemail" name="weexformemail" style="font-family:Calibri;border-radius:20px" placeholder="E-Mail" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" maxlength="12"
           oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
           placeholder="Telefon Numarası" style="font-family:Calibri;border-radius:20px" class="form-control mt-4" aria-label="Phone" id="weexformphone" name="weexformphone" required />
    <input class="form-control-file mt-4" type="file" name="AttachedFile">

    <textarea type="text" class="form-control mt-4" style="font-family:Calibri;border-radius:20px" aria-label="Message" rows="3" placeholder="Bize Yazın" id="weexformmessage" name="weexformmessage" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></textarea>
   
    <button type="submit" class="button-62 mt-4" role="button" style="float:right;font-family:Calibri">Gönder</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `<form>` needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to support `<input type="file" />`.

Comment: Thanks for Dai's comment. I have tested it and it works well.

Comment: When I run it, it is no longer Null. Thank you for this, but now it does not send mail, although all values ​​are filled and proceeding without error.